# How can I solve the NA problem in AUC calculation with if statement in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate AUC. My data frame include 27 different columns and 49 rows and I aspect that the AUC code will calculate the AUC for each column. It works but some of my columns include NA values. I want that the code ignores NA and calculates the AUC with other values for that column. My code is:

```
 # df is the main data and m is transposed form of df 
 totalAUC <- NULL
 for(a in 1:nrow(df)){
 y <- m[2:50,a]
 x <- c(seq(from=0, to=240, by=5))
 AUC <- data.frame(x,y)
 net_auc.fn <- function(x,y) {
   auc <- ifelse(y[2] > y[1], (y[2]-y[1])*(x[2]-x[1])/2, 0)
   for (i in 3:length(x)) {
  if (y[i] >= y[1] & y[i-1] >= y[1] & !is.na(y[i])) {
    auc[i-1] <- ((y[i]+y[i-1])/2)*5-(y[1]*5)
  } else if (y[i] >= y[1] & y[i-1] < y[1] & !is.na(y[i])) {
    auc[i-1] <- ((y[i]+y[i-1])/2)*5-(y[1]*5)
  } else if (y[i] < y[1] & y[i-1] >= y[1] & !is.na(y[i])) {
    auc[i-1] <- ((y[i]+y[i-1])/2)*5-(y[1]*5)
  } else if (y[i] < y[1] & y[i-1] < y[1] & !is.na(y[i])) {
    auc[i-1] <- ((y[i]+y[i-1])/2)*5-(y[1]*5)
  } else {
    return(cat("i:", i, "Error: No condition met\n"))
  }
 }
    return(list(auc=sum(auc, na.rm=TRUE)))
 }
 netiAUC <- net_auc.fn(AUC$x, AUC$y)
 totalAUC <- rbind(totalAUC, data.frame(Number=a,aucL=netiAUC))
 }
```

But I received error because of the columns with NA

```
 i: 49 Error: No condition met
```

My data is at below but I couldn't write whole rows and columns (it's very long), just the problematic one. Because it works for all other columns (I calculated AUC for each column with this code), only didn't work at 23th column (240.min is 49th row). So I added this part of my data:

```
 220 10.1  6.2  11.3  13.4  3.1  8.8  5.7  3.9  6.6  10.3  11.4 7.4  8.9  5.9  8.3  6.9  3.8  6.7  10.2  5.3
 225  9.8  6.2  10.7  13.2  3.5  8.9  6.7  3.4  6.6  10.2  11.2 7.4  9.0  5.9  8.2  6.6  3.7  6.6  10.1  5.6
 230  9.4  6.0  10.2  13.1  4.8  9.1  7.2  3.1  6.5  9.5  10.8  7.4  9.1  5.9  8.3  6.3  3.6  6.6   9.9  5.8
 235  9.1  5.9   9.7  12.8  6.8  9.2  8.1  3.0  6.4  8.5  10.5  7.2  9.0  5.8  8.3  6.0  3.5  6.6   9.5  6.2
 240  8.8  5.8   9.1  12.1  8.1  9.6  8.8  3.1  6.4  7.6  10.2  7.1  8.5  5.8  8.3  NA   3.3  6.7   8.7  6.3
```

If someone help me, I will be very appreciated

Comment: The message is clear, for iteration 49 none of your conditions are met, so check why not.

Comment: ... and if you think the problem is in your data, then you need to share your data if we are to help you effectively.

Comment: @user2974951 I mentioned that the problem is NA.  i:49  is NA. I also have other columns with NA. I think that the code should ignore ? If I exclude NA, in this case, it gives error 'row numbers are not equal'

Comment: @Limey the problem is NA, i:49 is NA.

Comment: You think so, but the code thinks otherwise. You are checking if y[i] is not NA, what about y-i? Go through each condition and check if it works as expected.

Comment: @user2974951 I added my data and why I am thinking the problem is NA. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Is there someone to help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `y[i]` is `NA`, your if-else sequence will fall through and return the error message. The reason is that all `if` conditions will evaluate to `(NA & <something> & FALSE)`, the result of which is always `FALSE`. You'll have to figure out what behavior you want in this case, instead of returning the error message, based on your algorithm.

BTW, try to simplify your code by using vectorization, and get rid of the for loops.

Also, if you want better help, please post a self-contained example that can be run as is and also include the desired output.